# Add custom css class to wp-list-table row for custom post type

Tags: admin

Is there any way to add a custom css class based on post data in the custom post type admin table?

[image: wordpress custom class in admin table row]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution. Founded in [WordPress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/#user-contributed-notes)

```php
add_filter('post_class', 'set_row_post_class', 10,3);
function set_row_post_class($classes, $class, $post_id){
    if (!is_admin()) { //make sure we are in the dashboard 
        return $classes;
    }
    $screen = get_current_screen(); //verify which page we're on
    if ('my-custom-type' != $screen->post_type && 'edit' != $screen->base) {
        return $classes;
    }
    //check if some meta field is set 
    $profile_incomplete = get_post_meta($post_id, 'profile_incomplete', true);
    if ('yes' == $profile_incomplete) {
        $classes[] = 'profile_incomplete'; //add a custom class to highlight this row in the table
    }

    // Return the array
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `if ('my-custom-type' != $screen->post_type || 'edit' != $screen->base) {` (`||` instead of `&&`)