# Add custom css class to wp-list-table row for Media Screen

Tags: media, thumbnails

How to add class to the row of WP List Table in Media List page like the following.

[Add custom css class to wp-list-table row for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/409570/add-custom-css-class-to-wp-list-table-row-for-custom-post-type)

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of the css class?

Comment: @birgire, to add a specific class to the files with webp extension to make that row distinguish from others.